# Mongoose.deepPopulate is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I recently started to using [mongoose-deep-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate) [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) package for nested populate in my project. My project involves me to allow only a `school Admin` to insert data of the students for the respective schools and I should display the details of the `school Admin` who inserted the data with the student details he entered.

My `students` schema is as follows:

```
userId: {
    type: Object,
    ref: 'User'
},
ugId:{
    type:Number

},
firstName:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
lastName:{
   type:String,
   required:true    
}
```

Here you can see that the `userId` is referring to model called `User` whose schema is as follows:

```
//More Fields
mappedUserDetails2: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Students'
},
UserGroupID: {
    type: Object,
    ref: 'UserGroups'
}
```

In the `User` Schema, `UserGroupID` is referring into `UserGroups` Model whose schema is as follows:

```
 groupName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    unique: true
},
createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
updatedDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
uid: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1
},
mappedUserDetails3: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

The Data I posted is as follows:

```
{
 "userId":"55b7320173ceb5640e1b24a6",
 "ugId":3,
 "firstName":"AGGI",
 "lastName":"AGGIqa"
}
```

My code that performs the `deepPopulate` for `userId` and `userId.UserGroupID` for a given student on the `students` model that is as follows:

```
 Students.findOne({ _id: data._doc._id}).deepPopulate('userId', '-password').deepPopulate('userId.UserGroupID').exec(function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
             return res.json({
                              success: false,
                              exception: err
                            });
  } else {
             return res.json({
                              success: true,
                              userDetails: data
                            });
         }
 });
```

When I run the API on DHC,I didn't any output and using node-inspector I found that my API is breaking for the `deepPopulate`. Can somebody point out where I am making a mistake and what is the workaround?

Comment: Try changing your `ref` fields with `type: Object` to be `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId` instead.

Comment: Hi Johnny Do you have any idea why.deepPopulate('userId', '-password').deepPopulate('userId.UserGroupID') is not working? I changed the ref fields type:object to type: Schema.Types.ObjectId and still the API was breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the following format for my deepPopulate and it worked.

```
Students.findOne({_id: data._doc._id}).deepPopulate(['userId', 'userId.UserGroupID']).exec(function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
             return res.json({
                     success: false,
                     exception: err
             });
   } else {
           delete data._doc.userId._doc.password;
              return res.json({
                          success: true,
                          userDetails: data
                     });

         }

});
```